# Select SO reputation per post for a given user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, dataexplorer

I am currently working on an SQL query for [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) which selects all the posts of an user from Stack Overflow and displays how much reputation each post generated.

What I can't wrap my head around is how to count all the *upvotes*, *downvotes* and *accepts* for every post and then to calculate the overall reputation gain of each post.

So I would to group by the `Post id` display the `Total score` and show how much reputation is gained overall.

The reputation each vote produces can be seen here:

```
+-----------+----------+--------+
| Post type | Question | Answer |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| Upvote    |    5     |   10   |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| Downvote  |    2     |    2   |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| Accept    |    5     |   15   |
+-----------+----------+--------+
```

The database schema I am targeting can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

My query so far looks like this:

```sql
select 
  p.Id as 'Post id', 
  pt.Name as 'Post type',
  p.Score as 'Total score',
  (
    case vt.Id
      when 1 then 'Accept'
      when 2 then 'Upvote'
      else 'Downvote'
      end
  ) as 'Reputation type'
from 
  Posts p
join 
  Votes v
on
  v.PostId = p.Id
join 
  VoteTypes vt
on 
  vt.Id = v.VoteTypeId
join
  PostTypes pt
on 
  pt.Id = p.PostTypeId
where
  p.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
and 
  vt.Id in (1, 2, 3)
order by
  p.Score,
  vt.Id
asc
```

And the output it produces looks something like this:

[image]

I tried to group by `Vote type id`:

```sql
group by  
  vt.id
```

so that I could at least find out how many different votes each post accumulated by using  something along the lines of:

```sql
select
  ....
  count(vt.id)
```

but then I get an error that the `Posts.Id` column can't be resolved:

[image]

The current runnable but incomplete query can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1026929) (You have to input your *user id* for it to run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reputation per post is a bit more complicated than that.
In addition to Up/Down/Accept votes, there are also:

1. Bounties,
2. Rep caps,
3. The user's rep floor (no user can have less than 1 rep (usually)).
4. Community Wiki.
5. Spam or Abusive flags.
6. Upvotes count for different amounts on questions, depending on the site.
7. Many posts have no votes at all, so the SQL needs to reflect that. (Left join, COALESCE, etc.)
8. Do you count an approved suggested edit on a post (2 pts rep)?
9. Probably something else that I'm forgetting.

Depending on what you are really after, you might consider using [this API method instead](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history) (and then grouping the results by `post_id`).

Anyway, [**here's your query tuned up a bit**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1027036?UserId=5515060):

```
SELECT      p.Id      AS [Post Link]
            , pt.Name AS 'Post type'
            , p.Score AS 'Total score'
            , COALESCE (vtStats.AcceptRep, 0)   AS [Accept Rep]
            , COALESCE (vtStats.numUpvotes, 0)  *  (
                CASE  p.PostTypeId
                    WHEN  1  THEN  5  -- Questions on most sites
                    WHEN  2  THEN 10  -- Answers
                    ELSE  1  -- Should not happen, but don't zero out
                END
            ) AS [Up Vt Rep]
            , COALESCE (vtStats.DwnVtRep, 0)    AS [Dwn Vt Rep]
FROM        Posts p
LEFT JOIN   (
    SELECT      v.PostId
                , SUM (CASE v.VoteTypeId    WHEN 1  THEN 15  ELSE 0  END)   AS AcceptRep
                , SUM (CASE v.VoteTypeId    WHEN 3  THEN -2  ELSE 0  END)   AS DwnVtRep
                , SUM (CASE v.VoteTypeId    WHEN 2  THEN  1  ELSE 0  END)   AS numUpvotes -- Needs special handling
    FROM        Votes v
    WHERE       v.VoteTypeId IN (1, 2, 3 )
    GROUP BY    v.PostId
)
AS vtStats  ON  vtStats.PostId = p.Id
INNER JOIN  Posttypes pt    ON pt.Id = p.PostTypeId
WHERE       p.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:Int##
ORDER  BY   p.Score DESC
            , [Accept Rep] DESC
            , pt.Name
```

Comment: I've edited your query and added a "net rep" column, [here's the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1027408) :)

Comment: Okay, good. Keep in mind that both queries are just first-order *approximations*, for the reasons listed above (except #7 which is handled).  Also, on reread, I forgot to note that self-answers do not give any accept-vote rep.

Comment: Yes, maybe in the future I will enhance it to handle all the cases, but currently it is all that I need

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 select 
 p.Id as 'Post id', 
 pt.Name as 'Post type',
 SUM
 (
    case vt.Id
    when 1 then 15
    when 2 then 10
    else -2
    end
    ) as 'Total Score'
    .....
   GROUP BY P.Id, Pt.Name
   ORDER BY....
```